# Comparing exact values with many significant digits across columns

Tags: r, filtering, data-manipulation

I have a table of numbers with many, varying significant digits. I need to find the exact matches for these digits across columns - e.g.

```
find_mz_matches <- data.frame("mz1" = c(3.14222, 314.12003, 214.220, 
254.111223, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), "mz2" = c(3.14222, 456.2200001, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), "mz3" = c(300.112223, 456.2200001, 3.14222, 
254.111223, 900.232, 476.0012503, 459.00201, 500.60402, 300.4053102))
```

I want to know what values are shared between mz1 and mz2, mz2 and mz3, and finally between all three columns together.

So, comparing mz1 and mz2 should yield:

```
 mz1_v_mz2
 3.14222
 456.2200001
```

And comparing all three:

```
mz_all
3.14222
```

I have cobbled together something that almost works, but the problem is that it's rounding somewhere and my output includes numbers that are similar but not the same, e.g. 3.14222 should not match with 3.14223. It also includes NAs in the output, which is not desired.

```
duplicates_across1 <- find_mz_matches[find_mz_matches$mz1 
%in% find_mz_matches$mz2, ]
```

That should work to compare the first two columns, so I figured I would just take the output and do it again for the next comparison - compare the output of duplicates_across1 to find_mz_matches$mz3. For some reason, it doesn't catch the presence of 3.14222 between all three columns and I have no idea why.

```
duplicates_all <- duplicates_across1[duplicates_across1$mz1 
%in% find_mz_matches$mz3, ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very `lapply`-y answer that compares each combination and stores the results in a list. It should be flexible if you have more than 3 columns as well. Good luck!

```
# Creating all combinations of columns in a list (and flattening it with unlist)
combos <- unlist(lapply(2:ncol(find_mz_matches), combn, x = find_mz_matches, simplify = F), recursive = F)

# Checking for common elements
common_elements <- lapply(combos, function(x) Reduce(base::intersect, x))

# Renaming the elements
names(common_elements) <- sapply(lapply(combos, names), paste, collapse = "_")

common_elements
$mz1_mz2
[1] 3.14222      NA

$mz1_mz3
[1]   3.14222 254.11122

$mz2_mz3
[1]   3.14222 456.22000

$mz1_mz2_mz3
[1] 3.14222
```

Answer (score 1):

See `Reduce()`:

```
Reduce(intersect, find_mz_matches, accumulate = T)
Reduce(intersect, find_mz_matches, accumulate = T, right = T)
```

The argument `accumulate` is optional - it's only there to show you what's happening. For your use, you can take it out and it would result in 3.14222.

```
Reduce(intersect, find_mz_matches)
[1] 3.14222
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
find_mz_matches <- data.frame("mz1" = c(3.14222, 314.12003, 214.220, 
                                        254.111223, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), "mz2" = c(3.14222, 456.2200001, NA, 
                                                                                   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), "mz3" = c(300.112223, 456.2200001, 3.14222, 
                                                                                                                      254.111223, 900.232, 476.0012503, 459.00201, 500.60402, 300.4053102))
find_mz_matches$mz_allmz1mz2 <- ifelse(find_mz_matches$mz1 == find_mz_matches$mz2 ,find_mz_matches$mz1   , NA)
find_mz_matches$mz_allmz2mz3 <- ifelse(find_mz_matches$mz2 == find_mz_matches$mz3 ,find_mz_matches$mz2   , NA)
```

After that, I would combine the resulting columns if no conflict present.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but it seems something is still off. The third line returns the error 
    Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, mz_allmz2mz3, value = logical(0)) : 
    replacement has 0 rows, data has 9 
Is there some dependency on order here?